# How to use Tabbed navigation layout inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to put tabbed layout inside a fragment layout, i have tried many methods but none of them worked.
Things to be noted first are I am already having a navigation drawer with 4 fragments and I want to apply tabbed layout to one of its fragment not All.

This is my JAVA code of the fragment on which i want to use Tabbed layout ,i am using android studio v3.3

```
package com.androidapp.kjsscapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NoticeBoard extends Fragment {


    public NoticeBoard() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notice_board, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.NoticeBoard_Tab);

        final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.Mpager1);
        tabpageAdapter tabpageAdapter = new tabpageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

The currosponding xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NoticeBoard">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/NoticeBoard_Tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/White">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/TabItem_general"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="General" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/TabItem_admissions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Admissions" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/TabItem_scholarship"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scholarships" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/Mpager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/NoticeBoard_Tab" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The tab controller:

```
package com.androidapp.kjsscapp;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class tabpageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int countTab;
    public tabpageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.countTab = countTab;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Tab_General gen = new Tab_General();
        Tab_Admissions add = new Tab_Admissions();
        Tab_ScholarShip sch = new Tab_ScholarShip();
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return gen;
            case 1:
                return add;
            case 2:
                return sch;
            default:
                return gen;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countTab;
    }
}
```

I expect to view the fragments of tablayout inside the fragment of drawer layout as soon as the fragment of drawer is called. Kindly provide the solution if any

Comment: It has a slight delay because that's just how ViewPagers work.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce actually the thing is the tabs are not working at all